# Show/Hide Text Every Time An Arrow Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I need help showing/hiding text on a button click (specifically an arrow). I have a block of text that I have hidden and I need to slide it down in a time consistent with the arrow rotating 180 degrees. I also want it to do this only for the post above the arrow that was clicked. The solution I have come up with in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8obybt1d/1/) has many problems.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    var angle = -180,
        height = "100%";
    $(".down-arrow").click(function () { 
        $(".down-arrow").css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        });

        $(".blog-post").animate({
            'height' : height
            });
        angle -= 180;
        height = "50px";
    });
});
```

And these are the issues I am having:

1. It slides down way too fast

   Once it slides back up it won't slide down again.

   It does it for every post

Comment: Flagging for: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.* Please [edit] you question to include enough code to reproduce the bugs. (I considered just editing it myself except your fiddle doesn't duplicate bug #3 either.)

Comment: @BSMP I updated the fiddle so that it reflects the issue

Comment: @ghost1349 I have posted an answer which is dynamic for as many number of div's of `blog-post` you have.

Comment: Please do not change your code to match suggested answers. Your code should reflect the problem as it was originally stated. It does not help future visitors to see the problem solved in both the question and the answer.

Comment: I've reverted this post to reflect the version at the time everybody answered it. If you have follow up questions please ask them separately.

Comment: @BSMP I've rolled it back to what I think is the right version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be more dynamic and clean to use:

- First we will take `height`'s of all the `.blog-post` div's in an array.
- Now making `height: 50px` of the div, after once we know actual height of all the `div's`. Which will helpful in making div smooth slide as we know height's.
- Next on click of arrow class, we will **toggle class** which holds `transform:rotate` properties. Along with that we would check corresponding `.blog-post` div's height. So if it is more than `50px` we would make it `50px`, else we would take it's actual `height` from array and give to it.

Here is the JS/JQuery Code:

```
var totalNum = $('.blog-post').length; // Counting number of .blog-post div on page.
var i, myArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < totalNum; i++) {
    var curHeight = $('.blog-post:eq(' + i + ')').outerHeight();
    myArray.push(curHeight);
}

$('.blog-post').css('height', '50px');

$('.down-arrow').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('invert');
    var index = $('.down-arrow').index(this);
    var heightCheck = $('.blog-post:eq(' + index + ')').outerHeight();
    if (heightCheck < 51) {
        $('.blog-post:eq(' + index + ')').css('height', myArray[index] + 'px');
    } else {
        $('.blog-post:eq(' + index + ')').css('height', '50px');
    }
});
```

[Working : Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8obybt1d/11/)

**If you still do not understand feel free to ask.**

Comment: Glad that it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess you should convert the `100%` to pixels (with `$(this).parent().innerHeight()` or something like that, then it works well.
2. You should build some sort of toggle: keep track of which blog-post/arrow is up and which one is down (flag the blog posts or the arrows with some sort of class) and based on that, you should let it slide up or down.
3. Of course, you're referring to the post with a css selector. You should use a combination of `$(this)`, `.next()` and `.prev()` functions in order to get the right post(s).

Answer (score 1):

1. "It slides down way too fast"

Just set an animation duration. See the jquery.animate() documentation.

It seems that jquery is pretty buggy when it comes to animating using percentages. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10669 http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9505  Try using pixels instead of percentage  http://jsfiddle.net/8obybt1d/1/

2. "Once it slides back up it won't slide down again."

Because you are not changing the value of height back to hundred%

A rough piece of code:

```
if (height == "50px") {
    height = "100%";
}
else {
   height == "50px"
}
```

3. "It does it for every post"

Try using the 'this' keyword.

Comment: 1 does not work, jQuery has a default duration of 400 ms.

Comment: @TempestasLudi how do I override that 400ms?

Comment: You can pass the animation duration as the second parameter in your animate function call, like `$('.selector').animate({width:'0px'}, 16000);`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve point 2:

```
$(".blog-post").animate({
...
    height = (height === "50px") ? height = "100%": height = "50px";
});
```